# Semaphore: why is sembuf defined in sem.h but semun is not?

Tags: kernel, ipc, semaphore

I've been experimenting with linux IPC following [this tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/semaphores.html), and came up with the follow question.

In the sample code [semdemo.c](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/examples/semdemo.c), `semun` is explicitly defined by programmer, while `sembuf` is predefined in the header file, on my machine `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/sem.h`. Why don't we move the definition of `semun` to the header file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was done, this would break existing programs as the language C does not allow to double define a type.

The missing type definition is an heritage from AT&T that cannot be changed.

See the SunOS man page for `semctl()`:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man2/semctl.2.html

that was derived from the AT&T man page.

Comment: I see. Is there any related background story/reference online?

Comment: Thank you for the update. By the way I just found from APUE 3rd of Richard Stevens that `semun` is defined in FreeBSD 8.0 (page 568).

Comment: And because of this FreeBSD bug, we need a special autoconf test for portable software that likes to run on FreeBSD as well.